# How to add "export" function from JTable to excel or pdf?

Tags: java, mysql, excel, swing

Edit:
I've tried Apache POI, and successfully export it to excel by entering data manually
but, i want to display data from my MYSQL database using JTable? 
any suggestion?

Here's my code:

```
public void showAllSchedule() {
    String[] kolom = { "title", "description", "date", "level" };

    dtm = new DefaultTableModel(null, kolom);
    try {
        Statement stmt = koneksi.createStatement();
        String query = "SELECT * FROM jadwal ORDER BY date ASC";
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs.next()) {

            String title = rs.getString("title");
            String description = rs.getString("description");
            String date = rs.getString("date");
            String level = rs.getString("level");

            dtm.addRow(new String[] { title, description, date, level });
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    main_table.setModel(dtm);
}
```

Comment: Small corectio: exported will be model not table. Do You have problem with build menu "Export" on GUI or use PDF library? Two known are itext and pdfbox.

Comment: Csv would be the simplest, with or without a library, but JasperReports can use a TableModel as a data source and has the ability to export to excel & PDF to just name a few

Answer (score 0):

To write to excel you can use [Apache POI](https://poi.apache.org/).

There's also [JXLS](http://jxls.sourceforge.net/) which is a library written on top of POI. It allows you to create a *template* spreadsheet which contains the logic (ie loops) to generate spreadsheets from a model.

Comment: I've tried Apache POI, and successfully export it to excel by entering data manually.
but, i want to display data from my MySQL database using JTable? (like the one above)
any suggestion?